# postfix+dovecot multiple domains config

Tags: postfix, dovecot, domain

I'd like to setup 2 distinct mail services (that look completely separated for end-user) on one machine with 2 IP addresses and 2 domain names. I've started with my current config which is a postfix+dovecot with virtual domains/users using MySQL (it was setup some time ago with an online guide). I've added

```
localhost:smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
<ip1 here>:smtp      inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
<ip2 here>:smtp      inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o myhostname=domain2.com
```

so when I connect to smtp using another domain name, it has its own banner, but...

Outgoing messages are still delivered with ip address #1 which is rDNSed to domain1.com. How can I change my setup so outgoing mails from domain2.com are being delivered using ip2 interface (so email headers say `Received from: domain2.com` and not `domain1.com`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is possible using the `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` option. Have a look at [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20111231031211/http://www.kutukupret.com/2010/01/02/postfix-bind-sender-domain-to-dedicated-outgoing-ip-address/) and [this](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps).

Comment: It works, but `cleanup` process doesn't know that there are different `myhostname`s and all messages have `Message-ID` header in form of `<xxxxxx@domain1.com>` even if they're sent from domain2.com. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: I've fixed it already. The application used own method to send mails via SMTP. I've replaced it with PHPMailer 5.2 and Message-IDs are OK now.

Comment: Nice to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe multiple Postfix instances is what you're looking for. Reference:
http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html

You can bind two instances to different IP addresses (smtp_bind_address), set different banners (smtpd_banner), etc.